# if i have a 5oz container of cologne (liquid), but it is only 15ml, will i be able to take it on the plane?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, airport-security, hand-luggage

Will I be able to take it without having to throw it away? Do they measure on **ounces or milliliters**? its a **5oz** bottle **(not all the way full -used-)** and it has **15ml** and the requirements are **3.4oz and 100ml**.

Comment: The sizes in the American/imperial system and in Metric are the same, as near as they can get it. So 3.4 oz and 100 ml do express the same, the size of the container. And the quart or liter are for the plastic bag you need to use to put them in and those sizes are also almost identical.

Comment: I think your 5 oz bottle is actually 150 ml. Are you misreading it?

Comment: @Dennis indeed.  Five US fluid ounces is the same as 147.87 ml. The other possibility, of course, is that the bottle is actually 0.5 fluid ounces, and 15 ml.

Answer (score 16):

No. The rules are crystal clear. They are not in the business of measuring how much liquid you have, they judge based on the container. Even when it's crystal clear there is extremely little liquid they will demand throwing it away if it's in a too large container like a sip on the bottom of a water bottle.

Edit: as a rule maker, if your goal is to regulate liquids this is the only rule that makes sense. I am not saying the liquid rule makes sense I am just saying if your job is to make a rule then the only sane way is by container not contents.

Comment: I've never seen this enforced in practice. I always travel with 4oz toothpaste and hair product tubes, visibly under half full, and have never even been asked about them.

Comment: I had lemon juice in a 125ml container about quarter full seized. (On Wednesday, July 25, 2012 at LGA.)

Comment: They are not trowing as much liquid in the bins now as they used to do when the rules were just started, they still seize enough bottles or empty them into the bins, that I would not travel knowingly with anything oversize in my carry-on.